# jQuery getScript issue in IE

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

We have validation rules in an external JS file that is being called via jQuery getScript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.getScript('scripts/validation/createPosting.js', function(){ checkFoapalPercentage(); });
$.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

The script works fine in all other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, and Safari).

Any idea why we're getting a Javascript error (Object expected) on a line that's referencing a method in the external JS file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't have nearly enough info in it ... Where is `checkFoapalPercentage` defined (in `createPosting.js`)?  What does it return?  Which line is throwing the error?

I *think* you mean checkFoapalPercentage is defined in `createPosting.js`, in which case the error could be because IE is (correctly) trying to refer to an as-yet-undefined function.

If you post some more info, I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: checkFoapalPercentage is defined in createPosting.js. However, the line that is throwing the error is from the first javascript file, and here's the code:

Comment: $(":submit").click(function() { //h:commandButton
   tinyMCE.triggerSave();
   
   var $formId = "#" + $(this).parents("form").attr("id");

   if ($formId == $createPostingFormId) {
    validateCreatePostingForm($formId);
   }
});

Comment: the validateCreatePostingForm() is where the error is being thrown in IE. this function is defined in createPosting.js.

Comment: it turned out that the callback function to checkFoapalPercentage() was the cause of the issue. thanks!